# パソコンのゲームソフトを作る事ができる言語、制作実行に使うソフト

Tags: プログラミング言語

ざっくりとした質問で申し訳ないんですが、できるだけ細かく教えていただけるとありがたいです。

超初心者です。C言語勉強中です。

os windows-10

Comment: 「制作実行」というのは何を指してらっしゃいますか？（おそらくこの言葉って単体ではあまり使われないものと思います）

Comment: ざっくりした質問だと、細かく回答するのも難しいと思います。せめてどういったゲームを作りたいかくらいは追記していただいた方がアドバイスも集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: @ambition さん、今回は回答が書けそうだったので書いてしまいましたが、一般的に、質問をする際にはあなたご自身の情報をもっと書いて欲しいです。回答が書きにくいからという理由もありますが、あまりにもざっくりとした質問だと主観的な回答ばかり集まってしまい参考にならないからという理由もあります。もしちゃんと「使える」回答が欲しければ、どういったものが作りたいのかとか、自分のスキルはどのくらいなのかとか、必要そうな情報をできるだけ質問文に書くのがオススメです。もし今からでも詳しく書けそうであれば、新しく質問するかこの質問を編集するかしてみてください :)

Answer (score 5):

「パソコンで動くゲームを作りたい！　でも、どんなプログラミング言語を学べば良いのだろう？」――こういった思考から、「○○できる言語はありますか？」という発想に至ることは想像に難くありません。「ウェブサイトを作るには HTML と JavaScript、組み込みなら C、機械学習では Python が良く使われているらしい」みたいな話から、「じゃあ○○だとどうなんだろう？」という考えが浮かぶのは自然でしょう。

プログラミング言語の面白い点のひとつは、こういった質問に対して「**大体どんな言語でも良いよ**」と答えられるところだと思っています。そうです、[チューリング完全](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E5%AE%8C%E5%85%A8)なプログラミング言語であれば、どれだって良いんです。そして世の中に出回っているプログラミング言語はたいていチューリング完全です。他の言語でゲームが作れるなら、今お使いの言語でも大抵作れます。

ですから、とりあえず質問者さんの好きなプログラミング言語で何かひとつ簡単なものを作ってみれば良いでしょう。そして他の言語も色々見てみて、その上でご自身で判断するのがオススメです。

**ただし**、「○○できる」ということと「○○しやすい」ということは別の話です。機械学習では Python と書きましたが、もちろん他の様々な言語でも機械学習をすること自体はできます。しかし現在世界的に Python を使って機械学習をしている人が多い影響で、機械学習をするのに便利なライブラリがたくさんあったり、見通しの良いプログラムで開発できるフレームワークが整っていたり、困ったときに調べたら他の人も困っていて解決策がすぐ見つかる環境が整っていたりと、Python で書いていれば機械学習が "やりやすい" といった傾向は確かにあります。もし他の言語でやろうとすると、たとえば自分で様々なライブラリを書かなければいけなかったりと、ハードルが高い部分があるでしょう。一方で Python じゃなきゃ駄目ということもなく、たとえば最近だと Go で機械学習をする流れがあり徐々にライブラリなどが整備され使いやすくなっています。

では、パソコンのゲーム制作がしやすいプログラミング言語は何でしょうか？　これは答えにくい質問です。というのも、ゲームといっても色んなものがあり、また、色々な人がたくさん作っているからです。少なくとも機械学習の例のように「一番使われているのはダントツでコレ！」というのは私は聞いたことが無いです。

たとえば大きく分けて 2D か 3D かという時点で話が変わってきます。2D のゲームエンジンは C や C++ を使ったものがいくつかありますが、Java 製のものや Rust 製のもの、Python 製のものも知られています（他にもたくさん！）。パソコンで遊ぶといっても JavaScript で作ってブラウザ上で動かす場合もあります。あるいは WOLF RPG エディターのようなゲームを作るためのソフトを勧める場合もあります。3D でもやはり C++ を使う人はいますし、Unity を使うのであれば C# と言う人もいるでしょう。何となく C++ が多そうな印象はありますが、ゲームエンジンは C++ で書いてロジックは他の言語で書くという状況もあり、どんな場合でも一番かと言われると疑問です。とにかく色々あり、どれかが群を抜いてオススメとは言いにくい状況が続いています。

ですから、繰り返しになりますが、まずは質問者さんが好きなプログラミング言語で試してみれば良いと思います。いきなり大作を作ると大変でしょうから、まずは小さいものを作って感触を確かめてみてください。何が良いか選べなければ、たとえば検索して一番上に出てきたものを選ぶのでも良いでしょう。

もしプログラミングを学びたてなら、何かしら書籍などチュートリアルを買って、それにしたがってひとつ完成させてみましょう。ゲームは色んなプログラミング言語で作ることができますが、「どうやって作るか」のコアな部分は似通っていることが多いです。チュートリアルを済ませることでアルゴリズムやデザインパターンなど抽象的な概念を習得できれば、他の言語を使うことになっても比較的簡単に書けるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず「Unity ゲーム」で検索してみてください。言語はC#になります。
書籍もいろいろ出ていますので、買って読んで見てください。
https://proengineer.internous.co.jp/content/columnfeature/13439
https://tech-camp.in/note/technology/17625/
https://uinyan.com/unity_7days_kusoge_challenge/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCOTx2BOk4A&list=PLED8667EEZ9Yb_Mzmf1I7xlmhwRE1H906